# Extend Entity Framework Generate Class with another default constructor

Tags: entity-framework, constructor

I have a class that was generated by entity framework
it has an empty constructor.

I have a WPF grid with DatePicker as a CellEditTemplate.
When I open a new record, I get the date 1/1/0001

The solution is to make the bound value in the class behind this grid to have a default value.

How can I create a constructor to that class and set the myDate Property to DateTime.Now ?

And in General - how do I extend a Generated Entity Framework Class.

(I don't want to derive from that class, as the class is managed in another shared dll, which is shared between other projects as well. I need this only to my project - the model returns the original class, and I should not have "access" to that code)

Comment: What code generation are you using?